# "No missing values are allowed" error in R using knn.res

Tags: r

```
finaldata <- subset(iris, Species == "Setosa" | Species == "Versicolor")
set.seed(123)
rows <- sample(nrow(finaldata))
data <- finaldata[rows, ]
train <- rbind(data[data$Species == "Setosa", ][1:40, 1:4], data[data$Species == "Versicolor", ][1:40, 1:4])
test <- rbind(data[data$Species == "Setosa", ][41:50, 1:4], data[data$Species == "Versicolor", ][41:50, 1:4])
class <- factor(c(rep("Setosa", 40), rep("Versicolor")))
knn.res = knn(train, test, class, k = 3)
```

With my current code what I end up getting is an error that says no missing values are allowed. Is there a way to clear that error?

Comment: double check `iris` - data elements for comparison in `subset` are case sensitive, you might want small s and small v in `setosa` and `versicolor`...in addition, your `train` has 80 rows, so you might want 40 in `rep` for `versicolor` (`rep("versicolor", 40)`) to give you total of 80 for `class` to match in length...

Comment: if small s and v are needed for `setosa` and `versicolor` you might want to modify comparisons done in creating training and test data sets too

Comment: Thank you! I made it 40 and it worked